# Scala - SQL divide by count()

Tags: sql, scala, count

i am trying to divide by count of field "_1" using **/count(_1)** . Unluckily its is not working

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT _1, _2, _3, _12, _13, _14, _13*_14/count(_1) FROM GoldsteinTemp")
```

Further information:
I am working with Spark/Scala and built a DataFrame called "Goldstein" which i "converted" to GoldsteinTemp to use SQL-Commands onto my Data.

If i try

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(_1) FROM GoldsteinTemp")
```

for counting it is working perfectly.

Any ideas/solution why i can not divide by **/count(_1)** ?

Thank you

[Dataset and code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krEwy.png)

Comment: Which SQL lib are you using?

Comment: What data do you have, what result do you expect, and what result do you actually observe?

Comment: @cchantep First of my Code i use following:
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

Comment: @John Bollinger: Please see attached image "Dataset and code example"

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing aggregate functions and non-aggregate functions without any `GROUP BY`.

I don't know what Scala supports, but most SQL implementations should allow you to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    _1, _2, _3, _12, _13, _14,
    (_13 * _14)/(SELECT COUNT(_1) FROM GoldsteinTemp)
FROM
    GoldsteinTemp
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, i tried this. Unfortunately it did not workout for me.

Comment: Can you be more specific?